# Show that $\mathbb F^{ \;m \times n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F^{m n}$,where $\mathbb F$ is a field.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Show that $\mathbb F^{ \;m \times n}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb F^{m n}$,where $\mathbb F$ is a field.

---

We can show that both have the same dimension:
$$\text{dim}(\mathbb F^{ \;m \times n})=mn=\text{dim}(\mathbb F^{m n})$$

On the other hand from this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3964765/given-two-vector-spaces-v-w-with-finite-dimension-show-that-they-are-isomorphi/3964795?noredirect=1#comment8177704_3964795) we know there exists an isomorphism between the two vector spaces,hence the result.

I'm not sure if my argument is true.

Comment: Can you write in your question what $\mathbb F^{ \;m \times n}$ is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct.

If you denote $E_{ij}$ the matrix having all entries equal to zero except the one at $i$th-row and $j$th-column which is equal to one, then
$$\{E_{ij} \mid 1 \le i \le m, \, 1 \le j \le n\}$$ is a basis of $\mathbb F^{m \times n}$. Therefore $\dim \mathbb F^{m \times n} = mn.$