# Proving an Isomorphism of $\mathbb R$

Tags: linear-algebra

I need some help proving if $\mathbb{R}^m\times\mathbb{R}^n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$? Now I know that I have to let my Linear transformation map $T:\mathbb{R}^{m+n}\rightarrow W$, where $W$ is a vector space. And then from there I was thinking about defining a Skeleton that has $m+n$ tuple of vectors in $W$ and then from there use a Linear combination Mapping. Am I on the right track?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track, but it has been shown here multiple times (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965489/show-that-mathbb-f-m-times-n-is-isomorphic-to-mathbb-fm-n-where)).

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. This is my first time to this site and I am completely self Taught in mathematics

Comment: Let $x \in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ then consider vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{m+n}$ as $(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $((x_1,\dots , x_n), (y_1, \dots ,y_m)) \in \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m$ and consider the map

$$T: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$$
$$((x_1,\dots , x_n), (y_1, \dots ,y_m)) \mapsto (x_1,\dots , x_n, y_1, \dots ,y_m)$$

This map is certainly linear and bijective, hence $\mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^m \approxeq \mathbb{R}^{n+m}$