# What are the differences between $ \vec{a} \in \mathbb{C} ^{N}$ and $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times N}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

Could you please explain what the difference between: $ \vec{a} \in \mathbb{C} ^{N}$  and $\vec{a} \in \mathbb{C}^{1 \times N}$  are?

I thought both will have the same meaning , but I have found in one article these two notations, so it looks like they are different

Comment: They are isomorphic vector spaces, see [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3965489/show-that-mathbb-f-m-times-n-is-isomorphic-to-mathbb-fm-n-where), with the field $F=\Bbb C$. Here $F^{m\times n}={\rm Mat}_{m\times n}(F)$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Please correct me if I am wrong. I can use both notations and both will be correct, right?

Comment: "Correct" depends on what was defined in the lecture. One space is a space of matrices, the other consists of vectors in $F^n$. They are isomorphic vector spaces, but different.

Comment: @MatthewTowers Paper of the research group I joined recently, I am unsure if it is published and if I can share it without their permission.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I want to describe a vector ( my understanding) $ 1 \times N $ is its dimension ( column or row vector ( my case))

Comment: Then it is a $1\times n$-matrix. This is formally different from a vector in $F^n$ (but can be identified of course) - see the duplicate.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Can I say that column or row vector is isomorphic and use one of the notation I mentioned in the post?

Comment: Could you explain it for me who I am familiar only with basic math

Comment: I can't explain it better than the duplicate does. Start reading this post I have linked above. It is very clear and elementary.

Comment: In general , there are Similarities & Differences between those two notations. When what we want to know is the Differences which the Article Author wanted to highlight , then what-ever Similarities & Differences we list here will be unrelated guess work , which might even be invalid. That Author is the **"Ultimate Expert"** on what the Intention was !